# How to cut string with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have strings:

```
до 100(прошло до 15 лет)
до 100 (прошло от 15 лет)
до 75
до 100 (10 лет)
до 100 (10 лет)
```

I want to cut strings like

```
до 100
до 100
до 75
до 100
до 100
```

Comment: +1 for asking about regular expressions where it makes sense to use them! (ie not for parsing XHTML or URLs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
strings = ['до 100(прошло до 15 лет)',
           'до 100 (прошло от 15 лет)',
           'до 75',
           'до 100 (10 лет)',
           'до 100 (10 лет)']

strings.map! { |str| str[/до \d+/] }

p strings    #=> ["до 100", "до 100", "до 75", "до 100", "до 100"]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different approaches to this. For example, you could cut off the string starting at the first `(`, if the string has one. However, I like this more explicit regular expression approach:

```
regex = /^до \d+/
str = "до 100(прошло до 15 лет)"
result = str[regex] # "до 100"
```

The regular expression `/^до \d+/` matches instances of `до` and a series of digits that occur at the start of the string. The syntax `str[regex]` returns the first (and, in this case, only) match, or `nil` if there is no match.

Comment: +1 - I always forget the `str[/regexp/]` syntax (and you explained it more fully than Victor)!

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
cut = full.match(/^до \d*/)[0]
```

...that is, match anchored to start of the string the characters `до`, followed by any number of digits; return the whole matched part.